# Pegar as coordenadas da posição do mouse ao clicar

Tags: c#, .net, winforms, coordenadas

Tenho que traçar uma reta com ponto inicial e final,consigo fazer essa reta caso eu forneça essas coordenadas pelo teclado, mas quero fazer isso pelo clique do mouse,o primeiro seria o ponto inicial e o segundo o final e com os dados o algoritmo iria traçar a reta,como devo fazer?

É uma aplicação em Windows Forms em C#

Comment: Você quer a coordenada de acordo com o monitor ou com o componente que for clicado?

Answer (score 1):

Se você quiser as coordenadas de acordo com o componente que for clicado

```
Point coordenadas = control.PointToClient(Cursor.Position);
```

Se for de acordo com a posição no monitor

```
Point coordenadas = Cursor.Position;
```

[`Point`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/pt-br/library/system.drawing.point(v=vs.110).aspx) é uma classe que contém as propriedades **X** (posição horizontal) e **Y** (posição vertical).

Comment: Com esse codigo eu apenas mostro as coordenadas quando movimento o mouse, eu quero armazenar a coordenada do ponto que eu clico

Comment: Não entendi seu problema. A variável `coordenadas` não está armazenando o local que foi clicado?

Comment: @GuilhermeBueno Você colocou o código no evento de `click`? Dê-me mais detalhes sobre o seu problema...